# Problem after installing phpmyadmin

Tags: server, mysql, php, webserver, phpmyadmin

I installed apache, mysql, and php on my Ubuntu 12.04 server but after logging in all I see is a white screen displaying a forward slash.  Is there something else I need to configure or enable?

> /

```
    # phpMyAdmin default Apache configuration

Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin

<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        DirectoryIndex index.php

        <IfModule mod_php5.c>
                AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

                php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
                php_flag track_vars On
                php_flag register_globals Off
                php_admin_flag allow_url_fopen Off
                php_value include_path .
                php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp
                php_admin_value open_basedir /usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmya$
        </IfModule>

</Directory>

# Authorize for setup
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup>
    <IfModule mod_authn_file.c>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "phpMyAdmin Setup"
    AuthUserFile /etc/phpmyadmin/htpasswd.setup
    </IfModule>
    Require valid-user
</Directory>

# Disallow web access to directories that don't need it
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup/lib>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
</Directory>
```

Comment: Which URL are you trying to access?
Can you please post your phpMyAdmin's Apache .conf file?

Comment: @BrunoMartins I've added the conf file to my question. I'm trying to access localhost/phpmyadmin - I'm presented with a login page then proceed to enter user and PW and get the white page with a  slash

Comment: Did you install phpmyadmin before or after installing apache and mysql?

Comment: @Pieter after apache, mysql, and php

Comment: @CR47 Just wanted to make sure about that(sounded like something was mis-configured). Does apache's error log provide any indication of a problem/error?